# Network Hardware Not Recognized After Imaging

Tags: networking, lubuntu, adapter

***Problem***:  After imaging a machine with Lubuntu 14, the machine can't bring up/find eth0 and wlan0.  It says

```
Error getting hardware address for "eth0": No such device
```

***Clue***: I solved this issue last year, and if I remember correctly, **there was some file containing adapter info that I had to delete before capturing the image.**  That file was recreated automatically at boot for each machine imaged.

***Question***: I cannot remember where that sneaky file lives, so if someone can remind me (and subsequently make it easier to find for others who stop by) I'd (we'd) appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "imaging"? I can image many things, but I guess that this is not what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

The file is located at

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

The file name may or may not be different on other installs.  Deleting this file will cause it to be regenerated on next boot (automatically) and this should solve the connection problem.

**Bottom line:  Delete /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules before capturing an image of Ubuntu.**